# integration of star ranking plugins into jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

hast anybody already integrated a star ranking plugin (eg. http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/) into jqgrid? What is the best way to do this?

Thanks
Anatoliy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have done custom cells, I have either hooked into one of the grid events (`afterInsertRow`) or if using `gridview:true` then `gridComplete` or `loadComplete`.
Then simply use the `setCell` method to insert the html into the row.